# Ambiguous pre-compile error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

When deploying my ASP.NET MVC 3 application from VS2012 RC I keep getting the below error. I am guessing something in my code is incorrect, however, I cannot determine from the error information where the problem code resides. This code builds on my home and work PC. Any Help?

```
d:\temp\zb5bedyk.2dr\temp\root\6b14f900\b1889a38\App_Web_nrwr2tuj.0.cs(37): error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'long' is a keyword
d:\temp\zb5bedyk.2dr\temp\root\6b14f900\b1889a38\App_Web_nrwr2tuj.0.cs(37): error CS1519: Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

[HttpCompileException]: d:\temp\zb5bedyk.2dr\temp\root\6b14f900\b1889a38\App_Web_nrwr2tuj.0.cs(37): error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'long' is a keyword
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileAssemblyBuilder(AssemblyBuilder builder)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileNonDependentBuildProviders(ICollection buildProviders)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.Process()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileAppInternal(VirtualPath startingVirtualDir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(VirtualPath startingVirtualDir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback, Boolean forceCleanBuild)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.Precompiler.Main(String[] args)




An error occurred during the website precompile. Precompilation failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optionally disable precompilation in application settings if you don't need it.

Also note that .NET 4.5 is not yet installed on AppHarbor infrastructure (it will be soon) so you may need to downtarget you project to 4.0.

Comment: thanks for the response. The application is .NET 4.0. I will try disabling precompilation, however it has already saved me by finding a couple errors in my Views. I will try some more tests on my local machine. I am not planning on going live for another week. Thanks again.